# Jenkins Build - Unable o find build.xml

Tags: jenkins, build.xml

I am new to Jenkins and I am having trouble to solve the following problem (lack of knowledge). When I make a change in my Git Repo, Jenkins makes a new build with the following ERROR MESSAGE:

```
ERROR: Unable to find build script at /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/toolxy/workspace/build.xml
```

Whereby the Name *toolxy* is the the name of the gitRepo itself. So my question is what I have to do to make the build successful? Where does this build.xml come from? Do I have to create the file manually? What for?

Do I need ant to have a successful build?

Comment: Are you trying to setup an ant build? build.xml is usually used for an ant build, and that file would be part of your source code. What are you trying to build? how are you building it? ant? gradle? maven? shell script?

Comment: Well my actual status is the following: I want to have the CI working before I begin with the Java Web-App (which I intend to implement in Eclipse). So before my first real commit I want to make sure that Jenkin works fine. So I realise I have a misunderstanding. Is it correct, that I first have to build the web app (simple version) in order to have a successfull build with Jenkins? I guess then I will go with Maven. Do you by any chance know what to enter in the configuration in the field "Goals" when choosing Maven for the build? Thank you for your help

Comment: Your Jenkins job can do something as simple as running a shell command to echo something. Do that to prove jenkins works before you mess with Maven or Ant. The Goals field for the maven build depend on your maven build file.

Comment: Thank you, that helped, Jenkins has build up successfully. Later on I will implement a simple app and try to build it with Maven. Your input was very helpful